# How to create XSI:Schemalocation dynamically with multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Hi all I am creating an XML file dynamically where I got struck with the following, I am having the following code which will assign schema location as follows

```
XmlAttribute attr5 = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
 string strXSDPath = "http://www.irs.gov/efile ";
 strXSDPath = strXSDPath + Server.MapPath("ReturnData941.xsd");
 attr5.Value = strXSDPath;
 returnData.Attributes.Append(attr5);
```

This works fine and this is giving in my XML file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:efile="http://www.irs.gov/efile" 
 ***xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile ReturnData941.xsd*"** />
```

But here I would like to have multple schema location with in the single as follows

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/../message/SOAP.xsd
               http://www.irs.gov.efile../message/efileMessage.xsd"
```

This is my XML generation code

```
XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);

            //XmlNode returnData = doc.CreateElement("SOAP");

            XmlElement returnData = doc.CreateElement("SOAP", "Envelope", "http://www.irs.gov/efile");



            XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
            attr.Value = "http://www.irs.gov/efile";
            returnData.Attributes.Append(attr);

            XmlAttribute attr1 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
            attr1.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            returnData.Attributes.Append(attr1);


            XmlAttribute attr3 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:SOAP");
            attr3.Value = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
            returnData.Attributes.Append(attr3);

            XmlAttribute attr4 = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:efile");
            attr4.Value = "http://www.irs.gov/efile";
            returnData.Attributes.Append(attr4);

            XmlAttribute attr5 = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            attr5.Value = strXSDPath;
            returnData.Attributes.Append(attr5);
```

So can some one help me

Comment: You haven't given any indication about how to obtain all the URI / XSD correspondences.  Are they listed somewhere?  If so, where?

Comment: `JLRishe` I will have them in my application only

Answer (score 0):

With only the information that you "have them in your application only", I can't provide you anything more dynamic, but assuming you can use Server.MapPath() to get all of the file paths, this should work to get the value you want:

```
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"http://www.irs.gov/efile","ReturnData941.xsd"},
    {"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "SOAP.xsd"},
    // add as many more of these as you need
};
string schemaLocationValue = 
  string.Join(" ", pairs.Select(p => p.Key + " " + Server.MapPath(p.Value)).ToArray());
```

Then you would just use that `schemaLocationValue` string as the value of the `schemaLocation` attribute.